# Replacing all occurences in a string in javascript issue

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my js code:

```
html = html.replace("/["+increment+"]/gi", '[' + counter + ']');
```

where increment is 0 and counter is 1
or

```
html = html.replace("/[0]/gi", '[1]');
```

My version does not replace the [0] with [1] in my string. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor as the regex is dynamic

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\[" + increment + "\\]", 'gi')
html = html.replace(regex, '[' + counter + ']');
```

Also you could sanitize the dynamic variable if you want

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    //A escape function to sanitize special characters in the regex
    RegExp.escape = function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}



//You could also escape the dynamic value it is an user input
var regex = new RegExp("\\[" + RegExp.escape(increment) + "\\]", 'gi')
html = html.replace(regex, '[' + counter + ']');
```

Comment: ok, but what about this format "@[0], 0" into "@[1], 1" ? thx

Comment: @JozsefNaghi `var regex = new RegExp('@\\[' + increment + '\\],\s' + increment, 'gi')
html = html.replace(regex, '@[' + counter + '], ' + counter);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
html = html.replace(new RegExp("\\["+increment+"\\]", "gi"), '[' + counter + ']');
```

This makes use of the dynamic values.